# Unable to use GET_PAGE_NAME keyword with multiple GO_TO Page

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, pageobjects

I am creating a Suite File where a TestCase contains multiple PageObject and to get_page_name where I am landed.
Getting below error
[Error if 2 pageobject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOcAB.png)

[Suite File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSsud.png)

Suite File

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the code and error in your question. It would also help if you told us where you're getting PageObjectLibrary from. Is it a custom library you wrote, or one from the internet?

Comment: used the [PageObjectLibrary](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary) from Internet. The sample code I used from the test folder of above PageObject repo. Just added 1 more GO TO page on [setup] of 1 TC for HomePage validation

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. It appears you're not loading page object libraries correctly.

Comment: Used same demo test and same folder structure which is provide under [robotframework-pageobjectlibrary](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary/tree/master/demo). Please replace line 28 of demo.robot with below `Login smoke test
    [Setup]  Run Keywords
 ...  Go to page  LoginPage
 ...  AND  Go to page  HomePage
 [Tags]  123
    Login as a normal user
 ${page_name}  get page name
 log  ${page_name}
    The current page should be  HomePage`

Comment: Please don't provide instructions or code in a comment. Instead, [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

two methods are defined with the same name "get page name" in the files "HomePage" and "LoginPage"